# Is there a typed language that compiles to python?

Tags: javascript, python, typescript

This maybe an obvious one, but as a JavaScript dev, I see all the hype around TypeScript, and I kind of share the enthusiasm.

While admittedly outsider to Python, I was wondering, what is the reason behind Py not having a similar option (e.g. typed Python)? If it is so warmly welcomed by most JS devs, why isn't there something on the horizon for Py? Or is there?

Thank you!

Comment: Python has optional typing, that can be enforced by static checkers like [pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) (made by Microsoft just like Typescript).

Comment: Python is both dynamically and strongly typed, it's just not statically typed. (some people use strongly typed to mean both statically typed and strongly typed, which is why they may claim Python is not strongly typed, but that's just stretching the definition a bit)

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of demand. TypeScript requires explicit types, where JavaScript has implicit types. Meaning it will convert the data type at runtime. This isn't much of a problem if the operation result is obvious, (Python makes it more obvious than JavaScript).

For example, what do you expect to get if you subtract a string with a number in it from a number? JavaScript will convert that string to a number and just subtract it, while Python will throw an error. This might seem convenient for JavaScript to do at first but can lead to hard to debug errors down the road.

JavaScript

```js
>>> 22 - "2"
20
```

Python

```py
>>> 22 - "2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

There is a natural higher demand for JavaScript with types because of these design considerations, where Python has none (that I know of).

Note as well that JavaScript dominates as the programming language of the web, meaning you pretty much have to use some kind of JavaScript these days to get dynamic content.

Python is more suited to run on local machines, where you could just as well run C, C++, etc.
So why would you want to make a high-level language that compiles to another high-level language instead of C, C++, assembly, etc that will yield you significantly more performance?

This isn't to say there aren't to-python-converters, there probably are but the demand is rather low.